# FileNotFoundError Try and Except seems to not be working

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

```
 def make_sender(self):
        a = False
        y = input("Make sender (Y/N)?")
        if y.lower() == "y":
            a = True
        while a == True:
            s = input("Enter folder name : ")
            t = input("Enter profile name: ")
            try:
                p = os.getcwd()+("\profiles")
                d = os.path.join(p, s,t)
                with open(d+".txt","w") as f:
                    print(">>> Opened ")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print(">>> File not found ")
            
            with open(d+".txt","w") as f:
                temp = input("Full Name: ")
                temp = temp.title()
                f.write(temp+"\n")

                temp = input("House Number: ")
                f.write(temp+"\n")

                temp = input("Street Name : ")
                f.write(temp+"\n")
                
                temp = input("Postcode    : ")
                f.write(temp+"\n")

                temp = input("Email       : ")
                f.write(temp+"\n")
            a = False
```

Thought that my code would keep running until correct data is entered. Think my try and except is built wrong. I've got the correct except code but think the indents or something is wrong.

Comment: You still try to open that file although an error was raised

Comment: Look over your code line by line. Each time you see a compound statement, consider whether the next line is supposed to be part of it. If it isn't, unindent that next line and the following ones.

Comment: After print file not found put `continue`

Comment: You open the file even if there has been an error. You probably meant to indent the whole `with...` block one level less. Also, you should really, really take the habit of using meaningful variable names, all these one letter variables make your code uselessly harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move your with block out of loop or put it under else block. First choice will require additional check for `a` (or simpler `return` at the beginning if `y.lower != 'y'`. I think the following approach is cleaner:

```
 def make_sender(self):
        y = input("Make sender (Y/N)?")
        while y.lower() == 'y':
            s = input("Enter folder name : ")
            t = input("Enter profile name: ")
            try:
                p = os.getcwd()+("\profiles")
                d = os.path.join(p, s,t)
                with open(d+".txt","w") as f:
                    print(">>> Opened ")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print(">>> File not found ")
            else:
                with open(d+".txt","w") as f:
                    temp = input("Full Name: ")
                    temp = temp.title()
                    f.write(temp+"\n")

                    temp = input("House Number: ")
                    f.write(temp+"\n")

                    temp = input("Street Name : ")
                    f.write(temp+"\n")
                
                    temp = input("Postcode    : ")
                    f.write(temp+"\n")

                    temp = input("Email       : ")
                    f.write(temp+"\n")
                    
                break
```